# How do I perform a batch operation on files using Imagemagick on CLI

Tags: command-line, 16.10, imagemagick, batch

I have a working command.  Now I need to know how to apply it to a bunch of files at once so as to automate the process.  I tried the below commands and it didn't work.  I'm trying to use Imagemagick convert command to perform an operation on 39 PNG files.

P.S.  I could not make the code button work to wrap the code in code tags.  Will someone please do so for me, thank you.

This command does nothing, just returns to a prompt.

```
find ./ -name  '*.png'
```

```
find ./ -name  '*.png' -exec sh -c 'convert  "$1" -shave 50x50 -bordercolor white -border 1x1 -fuzz 70% -trim "/home/nate/Pictures/trim/${1##*/}"' sh {} \;
```

```
find ./ -name  '*.png' -exec sh -c 'for f; do convert  "$f" -shave 50x50 -bordercolor white -border 1x1 -fuzz 70% -trim "/home/nate/Pictures/trim/${f##*/}"; done' sh {} +
```

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do filename=`basename "$file"`convert "$file" -shave 50x50 -bordercolor white -border 1x1 -fuzz 70% -trim "/home/nate/Pictures/trim/$filename" done < <(find ./ -name "*.png" -print0)
```

Comment: What's the output of `find . -iname '*.png'`?

Comment: Nothing at all.  Just returns to the prompt.  I use 16.10.

Comment: That means it couldn't find any PNG files

Answer (score 0):

Ah.  Somehow I ended up renaming the png files to numbers.  I renamed them with .png.  It work.  Solved.

Comment: I had renamed 39 files from scan-1.png to simply png with no extention.  I renamed the files to 1.png, 2.png, 3.png.  I simply could not find the files because I was looking for an extension called .png where the files were simply png